# Write a dictionary like string to JSON file without quotes in R

Tags: r, jsonlite

I wish to export a few strings from R into a JSON file. However, I do not want to have the quotation marks around a certain dictionary like string while exporting the file.

For example

Here are the items I am trying to write to a JSON file.

```
x <- c("apples", "oranges")
y <- "{'add': 'bananas'}"
z <- list("mangoes", "pears")

full_line <- c(x, y, z)

jsonlite::write_json(full_line, "output.json", pretty = T, auto_unbox = T)
```

I would like the string `"{'add': 'bananas'}"` to be written to the file `output.json` without quotes as follows

```
"apples"
"oranges"
{'add': 'bananas'}
["mangoes", "pears"]
```

How can I achieve this in R?

I am currently using the `jsonlite` package and its function `write_json` for this purpose.

So far I have tried putting the string inside the `noquote` function as well as tried `cat` and adding `quote = F` in the writeJSON function. But none of them work for my purpose.

Comment: There are no double quotes in any of those values. That's just the way that `print.default` displays them at the console. You can check by applying `nchar(.)` to them.

Comment: Do you mean the output file does not have quotes for this problem?

Comment: No, I meant that any quotes in the output file were added by the `write_json` function.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to prevent this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `cat` you will need to make your last item into a character value rather than having it as a list, since `cat` does not handle lists, Then you could use `sapply` to run `cat` over the three (atomic) items with "\n" `paste0`-ed after each,

```
x <- c("apples", "oranges")
y <- "{'add': 'bananas'}"
z <- '["mangoes", "pears"]'

full_line <- c(x, y, z)

sapply( paste0(full_line, sep="\n"), cat, file="~/out.txt", append=TRUE)
```

If the file was empty at the beginning of the operation, then you would get this:

```
apples
oranges
{'add': 'bananas'}
["mangoes", "pears"]
```

If you wstill want double quotes around `apples` and `oranges`, then you would need to make that explicit.